# how to substring in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, substring

My javascript code ,

```
var docPath = document.location.pathname.toString()
```

returns

```
/myFolder/UserControls/myUserControl.ascx
```

I want to subString likes

```
/myFolder/UserControls/
```

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mhh..

```
var n=str.lastIndexOf("/"); // get the last "/"
var result = str.substring(0, n); // only keep everything before the last "/" (excluded)
```

Does what you want ?

Comment: substring(0,n+1) to also keep the last "/"

Answer (score 2):

Your question is no very much clear. You may try

```
var docPath = document.location.pathname.toString()
.substring(0,document.location.pathname.toString().lastIndexOf("/")+1);
```

Comment: Two too much ";" at the end (1 after parenthetis, 1 before) ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>

var str=document.location.pathname.toString();
document.write(str.substring(0,str.lastIndexOf("/")));;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `match` string method:

```
var fullPath = '/myFolder/UserControls/myUserControl.ascx';
var path = fullPath.match(/(.+\/)/);
alert(path[1]); // This will output "/myFolder/UserControls/"
```

You can verify the working at the following JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H5PGb/

Comment: Regex are the most powerfull/generic solution, but they are expensive (for performances). So if you can avoid them, avoid them.

Answer (score 2):

```
var x = docPath.lastIndexOf("/");
var substr = docPath.substr(0, (x+1));
```

This will look for the last "/" character in your string and return it's position. Then it will take your string and put the characters from 0 to your last "/" character and put it into the substr var.

Answer (score 1):

```
var docPath = document.location.pathname.toString();
var sub = docPath.substring(0,docPath.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
```

This should work